# How to make comlex query to Wordpress database

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I tried to make a complex query to WordPress database but it did not work, so I ask for help.
First I need to get the meta value from one table, and then using it to get the ID from another table.
For this I use the following code:

```
global $wpdb;
$event_ID   = 306;
$meta_value = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta
    WHERE meta_key = 'driver_type' AND post_id = '{$event_ID}'" );
$event_type = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT post_title FROM wp_posts
    WHERE ID = '{$meta_value}'" );
```

I would like to optimize the query. Tried to make here such request but it returns to me 1 instead of the necessary value:

```
$complex = $wpdb->query( "SELECT t2.post_title, t1.meta_value FROM wp_postmeta AS t1
    INNER JOIN wp_posts AS t2 ON t1.meta_value = t2.ID
    WHERE meta_key = 'driver_type' AND post_id = '{$event_ID}' GROUP BY t1.post_id" );
```

Please tell me how to make the correct complex query in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to just chain together your two queries:

```
SELECT post_title
FROM wp_posts
WHERE ID = (SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta
    WHERE meta_key = 'driver_type' AND post_id = '{$event_ID}');
```

Or, you could try doing a join:

```
SELECT p.post_title
FROM wp_posts p
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta m
    ON p.ID = m.meta_value
WHERE
    m.meta_key = 'driver_type' AND post_id = '{$event_ID}';
```

Comment: thank you! your first solution is working fine to me